# Symfony2 FOSRestBundle solely json

Tags: json, symfony, fosrestbundle

I started working with FOSRestBundle building restful api. I wan't to make code as simple and clear as possible. I will use api only for json responses (No templates). Now I saw "@View" annotation which is quite nice and when using it return statement becomes as simple as returning "$data" object

```
//http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/3-listener-support.html 
/**
 * @View()
 */
public function getUsersAction()
{
    return $data;
}
```

But this requires me to create template, and I don't realy need nor wan't to that.

What would be nice if I could just simply return any $data (or at least array) and it would be automatically formatted into json response. Is that possible if so what configuration of this setup might look like?

Answer (score 0):

> "When view_response_listener is set to true instead of force and
>   @View() is not used, then rendering will be delegated to
>   SensioFrameworkExtraBundle."

You need to set annotations to false in SensioFrameworkExtraBundle:

```
sensio_framework_extra:
view:    { annotations: false }
```

and

```
fos_rest:
view:
    view_response_listener: force
```

You can look at this example https://github.com/liip/LiipHelloBundle/blob/master/Controller/ExtraController.php

Comment: I did what you suggested, but it still gives error: Unable to find template

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible to return response as JSON with FOSRestBundle. For that you can set config options like this:

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            xml:  true
            json: true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: ^/, priorities: [ json, xml, html ], fallback_format: ~, prefer_extension: true }
```

Note in above code view_response_listener is set to 'force'.

and in your controller you can send data as JSON response by creating $view object as follows

```
$view = View::create();

$view->setFormat('json');

$view->setStatusCode(200)->setData($data); 

return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, but anyway, why would I need to add options for "templating_formats:
            html: true" if I only want so serve json?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "This doesn't work" ? What error you are getting? Stating "This doesn't work" doesn't help us in debugging. Of course you can leave out 'templating format' option if you are not going to use it.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete statement. It gives unable to find template error.

Comment: The issue is the accept header. you must either send application/json; charset=UTF-8 or application/json as the Accept header in your request

Alternatively prefer_extension needs to be enabled and then you can simply add a .json to your route pattern.  Checkout the discussion: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/518#issuecomment-22162359

Comment: What you're saying seems to be true, If I set default _format parameter in routes to json, I don't get this error anymore, however I tried setting Accept header but then I get same error again. I would prefer using headers instead of additional format parameter, but maybe there more configuration for that, because current configuration doesn't work with headers

Comment: I finally make it work, your example was 99% correct, but for some strange and yet unknown for me reason line: format_listener: true was messing things up, when I removed it, everything started working as expected. If you would edit your answer or could explain why it was like so, I would gladly accept your answer.

Comment: Glad it helped you :) removed format listener from my posted answer, if possible I will investigate issue further at my end